# Ionic 3 read SMS plugin for OTP Verification

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I have used below plugin
cordova-plugin-sms

**Methods :-**

```
watchSMS() {   
  if(window.SMS) window.SMS.startWatch(function(){  
    console.log('Succeed to start watching SMS');   
    document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', this.smsArived);
  }, function(){   
    console.log('failed to start watching SMS');  
  });  
}

stopWatchSMS() {   
  if(window.SMS) window.SMS.stopWatch(function(){ 
     console.log('Succeed to stop watching SMS'); 
  }, function(){  
     console.log('failed to stop watching SMS');    
  }); 
}

smsArived = (result: any) => { 
    console.log("SMS DATA 2" + smsData);
    this.stopWatchSMS();   
}
```

using the above code for reading otp from SMS for ionic 3 getting below error can any one help

> file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 312 : Error in Success
>   callbackId: SMS329868448 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'smsArived'
>   of null I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(312)] "Error in Success callbackId:
>   SMS329868448 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'smsArived' of null",,
>   source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to implement this using pure javascript which leads to unwanted effects when working with Ionic/Angular/Typescript. `this` in your success callback function of `startWatch` does not reference the class scope so the `smsArived` method is not found.

*So how to do this the Angular/Ionic way?*

First of all do not access global objects directly (`window`, `document`) this is bad for performance and maintainability.
To use a cordova plugin which is not included in ionic-natvie you have to tell typescript that the plugin handle (`SMS`) exists:

```
declare var SMS; // put this at the same level as your imports
```

Then you have to modify your `watchSMS` function as follows:

```
watchSMS() {   
  SMS.startWatch(
    success => {

    },
    error => {

    }
  );
}
```

By using [arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) for your callbacks `this` has the correct scope. So now we need to work around your direct call to `document.addEventListener`: In Angular4 this is done by injecting the `Renderer2` class:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core'; // the import
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {} // inject it in your constructor
```

Now you can add the event listener in the success callback and call your `smsArived` method with the events data when an event is captured:

```
let removeSmsListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'onSMSArrive', (event) => {
   this.smsArived(event);
});
```

Notice that again you have to use an arrow function to keep the context of `this`. To clean up behind you, you can call `removeSmsListener()` because the `listen` method of the renderer returns a function.

It should be easy now to apply these changes to the other functions.

Comment: I'm using Ionic 3+ and Angular 4+ for my app but 'onSMSArrive' event is not getting triggered on SMS arrival.